# Pausing and restarting Application.Idle

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a game using `winforms` (my teacher told me). So, I have a game form, and code in `Load_Event`:

```
public void Game_form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Idle += TimerCallback;
}
```

I'm calling the method `TimerCallback`, in which I change all my objects positions and after that do `Invalidate()`:

```
public void TimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Bonus_move();
        Objects_move();   // all this methods do changing objects positions
        Player_move();
        Invalidate();
}
```

Yeah, it works, objects change positions without any problems, but when I press key `Esc` - the second form should open (like pause menu) and animation should be stopped.
For this I have code:

```
Application.Idle -= TimerCallback;
```

Okay, game loop is stopping, I can restart game (just do restart game form ), but i can't continue my game process, using:

```
Application.Idle += TimerCallback;
```

Game process does not continue. What is the problem?

Comment: It is a pretty problematic way to implement a game loop, burning 100% core is never a very desirable feature and animation rate depends entirely too much on machine horse power.  But surely all that you need is a *bool* variable.  Set it to true when you detect the ESC key hit and test it in your event handler to know to do nothing.  Consider getting it more right, minus the failure mode you discovered, with a plain timer.  The one from the toolbox, set its Interval to 15 or 31 msec to get consistent frame rates.

Comment: So, i have 1 mor question. I tried to use bool in TimerCallback(my method for changing positions and redrawing) and i had nothing. Just static screen. So, where i should have this bool?

Comment: Make it a field of your Form class so both the KeyDown and the Idle event handlers can access it.

Comment: Oh my god, that was my mistake. Sorry. By mistake i wrote : while (bool) instead if (bool). Sorry man, thank you, my apologise for this